# Access Record from Grid CellEditing Field

Tags: gridview, extjs

I use a Grid with a CellEditingPlugin and two DateColumns (startdate and enddate). Both column are assigned a datefield, named startdateEditfield and enddateEditfield.

If both dates are the same and startdate is changed, I want to change enddate as well.

So I made

```
var start = Ext.getCmp("startdateEditfield")
start.on('change',function(field,newValue,oldValue) {
    var end = Ext.getCmp("enddateEditfield")
    if(end.getValue()==oldValue) end.setValue(newValue);
});
```

which does not work because enddateEditfield does not exist, since I am editing startdate, not enddate. But how can I access the record that I am editing?

Comment: check [edit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-edit) event of `CellEditing` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

On some event handler you can get access of the record using :

```
var selectedModel = this.up('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
selectedModel.set('dataIndexOfNextCol', "Success");
```

Check out my answer to this question,it might help you : [ExtJs. Set rowediting cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390900/extjs-set-rowediting-cell-value)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try with beforedit and edit listeners...

this is how i managed to do it

```
Ext.define('Foo.view.BarView', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    alias: 'widget.foobarview',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        // this is our last selected record        
        this.lastRecord = null;

        this.plugins =  [{
            ptype: 'cellediting',
            clicksToEdit: 1
        }];

        this.listeners = {
            beforeedit: function(editor, obj){
                this.lastRecord = obj.record;
            }
        };

        this.columns = [
            {
                dataIndex: 'foo',
                text: 'bar',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function(datefield, newValue, oldValue, eOpt){
                        me.fireEvent('myEvent', datefield, me);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

And now in your controller you can take that last selected record when changing values in datefield from the grid...

```
Ext.define('Foo.controller.BarController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',


    stores: ['your stores'],

    views: [
        'your views'
    ],

    init: function() {
        var me = this;
        'foobarview': {
            myEvent: this.onFireMyEvent
        }
    },

    onFireMyEvent: function(field, grid){
        record = grid.lastRecord;
    }
});
```